# Changing Zinc acetate dihydrate to Zinc acetate

Tags: experimental-chemistry

For some Chemistry work in the laboratory, I needed Zinc acetate but laboratory only has Zinc acetate dihydrate. Is there any way to convert hydrate form to anhydrous form? Maybe by heating or any other method?
If by heating, how much time and temperature I should give?

Comment: Heating would work.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is your friend...[Zinc Acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_acetate)

> > Decomposes at 237 °C (459 °F; 510 K)
> >     (dihydrate loses water at 100 °C)

So heating to 120-130 °C for several hours would remove the water, but not be hot enough to decompose the salt. The dried salt will be hygroscopic of course so store it in a desiccator.